# Specific automotive industry SQL Query over 8+ tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, search

**Problem**

I need to search across a lot of tables and I can't get the query to work.

**Information setup**

Working in the automotive industry. They have the concept of MTOC (Model, type, option and colour). These four items combine to create a product type. The product type is then used for multiple instances of a product identified by a VIN (vehicle identification number).

**ER Diagram**

I have structured the data in the following way:

[image]

**Output**

I am trying to write a search query across most of these tables so that the users can view a list of product (MTOCs) grouped by Model. The output should look something like this:

```
+----------|--------------+
| Model A  | MTOC Z       +
+----------|--------------+
| Model A  | MTOC Y       +
+----------|--------------+
| Model A  | MTOC X       +
+----------|--------------+
| Model B  | MTOC J       +
+----------|--------------+
| Model B  | MTOC K       +
+----------|--------------+
| Model C  | MTOC N       +
+----------|--------------+
```

**Considerations**

I want to be able to search via all fields including VIN but there are millions of VIN records. The most optimal method is preferred.

Please also note it's one search string (one input field) to search across all tables looking for a hit.

**Example**

1. A user might type in Fireblade and press search.
2. A user might then type JZ2SD03UGHK and press search in a new search.

For context, example data in each of the tables is:

```
Model - CBR600RA
Nickname - Fireblade
Type - 3U
Option - 2
Colour - R344
Colour Description - Candy Apple Red
mtoc_name - CBR600RA3R1
VIN - JZ2SD03UGHK000999
```

My attempt fell short of being able to search across all tables, although it worked for some of the tables but not Item (VIN). I can upload it on request.

If the data structure is not set up for this please indicate what needs to change to make it work with your SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

**My Attempt plus help from Stackoverflow**

The following solution is getting close but not quite there.

```
SELECT
    model.model_name,
    product.mtoc_name
FROM
  mydb.item
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    mydb.product_item
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      mydb.product
      LEFT JOIN
      (
        mydb.product_mtoc
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          mydb.model
        )
        ON
          product_mtoc.model_id=model.model_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          mydb.type
        )
        ON
          product_mtoc.type_id=type.type_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          mydb.option
        )
        ON
          product_mtoc.option_id=option.option_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          mydb.colour
        )
        ON
          product_mtoc.colour_id=colour.colour_id
      )
      ON
        product.product_id=product_mtoc.product_id
    )
    ON
      product_item.product_id=product.product_id
  )
  ON
    item.item_id=product_item.item_id
  WHERE
    exists ( select * from mydb.product_item left join mydb.item on item.cbu_id = product_item.cbu_id where product_item.product_id = product.product_id and item.vin like '%JZ2SD03UGHK%' )
    or model.model_name like '%JZ2SD03UGHK%'
    or type.type_name like '%JZ2SD03UGHK%'
  GROUP BY model.model_name
```

Unfortunately this will return Model and MTOC but for only one Model/MTOC combination (many times). The query takes a long time to run.

If I take the second and subsequent lines of the where clause out (or model.model_name like '%... etc) it will work for the VIN. I need to add all the fields I am checking in here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mysql, but maybe this will help. in MSSQL I would created a Stored Procedure with my search criteria as parameters, then the stored procedure would look like this:

```
select whatever_columns
from product_mtoc pm
join Type t on t.type_id = pm.type_id
join colour c on c.colour_id = pm.colour_id
join product p on p.product_id = pm.product_id
.
.
.etc.
where 
(colour_name like '%' + @ColourName + '%' or @ColourName is null)
and
(colour_description like '%' + @ColourDesc + '%' or @ColourDesc is null)
and
(@vin is null or exists(select * from product_item pi join item i ont i.item_id = pi.otem_id where pi.prodcut_id = p.product_id and item.vin like '%' + @vin + '%' ))
and
.
.
.etc.
group by selected_columns_not_aggregated
```

you might need to use "Upper" or "lower" functions to make sure your search is not cases sensitive if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for your interest! MySQL and MMSQL are quite similar.In your answer I think you have just replaced the text entered by the user as a variable in the SQL string. I can do this via my programming language at runtime. That is not my issue. The issue is that I cannot enter a search entry that relates to vin and have the data returned in the output described above.

Comment: ok I have updated the query, the idea here is that in the 'vin' condition if it is null the second part will not need to be executed, so you'll not have to access that table with every search. the second part uses "exists" function in an attempt to make it faster as it will evaluate to true once it finds one record that matches the part of 'vin' you passed.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try add that in and see.

Comment: Ahh, I believe that worked for VIN... except now my model doesn't work. I'll update the question with my new code.